# multiply variables in two NetCDF files in single command

Tags: netcdf, nco, cdo-climate, ncks

I have two netcdf files:
file_1.nc with variables qty_1 and qty_2  and
file_2.nc with variables qty_3, qty_4 and qty_5.
I want a file with 3 variables qty_3=qty_3*qty_2; qty_4=qty_4+qty_2 and qty_5.

Now I am first copying the variables to file_2 using

```
ncks  -A -v qty_1,qty_2 file_1.nc file_2.nc
```

then I am doing math operation as,

```
ncap2 -A -s 'qty_3=qty_3*qty_2' -s 'qty_4=qty_4+qty_2' file_2.nc
```

This works, however, take some time.

Is there a way I can do this calculation in a single command ?

Comment: I think your method is the most efficient way it can be done with NCO

Answer (score 5):

If you aren't totallly dependent on NCO, you could do this with CDO:

```
cdo -selname,qty_3,qty_4,qty_5 -aexpr,'qty_3=qty_3*qty_2;qty_4=qty_4+qty_2' -merge file_1.nc file_2.nc out.nc
```